# How to call method inline during constructor

Tags: java, android, arrays

As an example, take the following.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[]{"a","b","c","d"};

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>().addAll(stringArray);
```

I am aware that I can call

```
Arrays.toList("a","b","c","d");
```

but this is just an example where I would want to call a method while creating the object (inline).

I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: This isn't a problem with "calling method inline during constructor".  It's simply that `ArrayList.addAll()` doesn't take an array.

Comment: Apart from that, addAll returns a boolean, not a List.

Comment: That depends on the API's implementation.  For example, Builder pattern implementation provides that kind of behavior, as well as StringBuilder allows you to call the constructor and call the append method inline.  For example: `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("hello ").append("world");`

Comment: @TobiasWeimer The issue is exactly what you stated. I want to know how to modify an object as I am creating it. This is an example but it could be any number of things. Eleazar gave a good example, of what I am looking for. Is there no way I can do this regardless of the object being used? The Builder object that was hinted below is what I am looking for, however I want to know if it is possible to do things like that with Standard List/Map objects.

Comment: @T-he-game No, you cannot do that in your example.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the API's implementation. For example, Builder pattern implementation provides that kind of behavior, as well as StringBuilder allows you to call the constructor and call the append method inline.

**For example:**

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("hello ").append("world");
```

**An example of Builder pattern - This is Just an example :-)**

```
SimpleBuilder myBuilder = new SimpleBuilder().withThisWord("Hello ").withThisWord("world").build();

System.out.print(myBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: This is very close, however I want to be able to use this style of building with the generic List/Map objects that Java has. Is this possible, without having to build my own builder class (in that case, I'll just deal with the fact that I need to use 2 lines to accomplish what I want(